# Conditionally Hiding Pricing; Need to Make Visible from Tag/Custom Taxonomy

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

1. Hide product pricing & add to cart button unless logged in
2. Sale items be visible, logged in or not, if visited from some kind of tag, category, or other taxonomy so that nobody sees the sales unless they are directed to them explicitly.

   - Example: All product prices are hidden, except on URLs with the tag "waffles-sale". This is a simple example but I think that explains what I'm after with 2.

I've accomplished 1. with a plugin, and more recently a short code; this works great:

```
add_action( 'init', 'bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' );

function bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() {   
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {      
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );   
 add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 31 );
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 11 );
}
}

function bbloomer_print_login_to_see() {
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __('Please login for pricing.', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

But this leaves me with two, which is making things visible conditionally. I am sorry if this is vague. I've scoured the web for answers but I'm coming up short. I feel like my vocabulary is holding me back; I don't know the words for the hooks or phrases that I'm describing. I would love to stop reinventing the wheel (I'm having to clone products/product categories to make only them visible from temporarily published pages for sales).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is controlling product visibility in this way possible? I would greatly appreciate anyone's more experienced two cents or solution to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (haven't tested), wrote it on rush, but it should help you in achieving what you need.

You need to define the query string then add/remove actions depending on what you need based on that query string.

Use the [get_query_string](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/):

```
// register query var
add_action('init','register_query_string');
function register_query_string() { 
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('my_query_string_name'); 
}

//check if it's in the url
    if ( get_query_var('my_query_string_name') ) {
   // remove/add actions for the query string
   elseif ( !user_not_logged_in()){
   //something when not logged in 
  }
 }
```

in case you need to check for query string and logged in, you can do something like

```
 if ( !get_query_var('my_query_string_name') && ( !user_not_logged_in()){
 // insert magic here
 }
```

Code goes into functions.php from your child theme (or a plugin).

Comment: Thank you kindly, I will see if I can't incorporate this this morning.